# can any one know how linkdin, and other platform sending local notification?

Tags: flutter

I wanted to know how linkdin and platform sending local notification on mobile phone aven after app is closed.
I am expecting to know solution to display local notification after app in terminate mode.
i wanted to hit api and after that wanted to show data on local notification.

Comment: [`OneSignal`](https://onesignal.com/)

Answer (score 1):

1. Dealing with Push Notifications:
   Set up a server to transmit push alerts, such as FCM.
   respond to incoming push alerts.
2. Make local announcements:
   Make a function that shows local notifications.
   When you have information to show in a notice, use this function.
   You can try this package for showing notifications
   https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications
3. Handling Terminated State:
   To handle alerts while the app is closed, configure a callback or background execution method.
   Using information from your API or push notifications, schedule notifications.
   you can try among these for your background purpose
   https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch or
   https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service

Comment: If you manage to set FCM and flutter local notifications correctly you won't need both packages provided in the 3rd step.
However,The app must not be executed in Debug mode